# How do I get a methods argument for an after plugin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, plugin

Is it possible to access an observed methods arguments in an `after[Method]()` plugin? For example, I want to write an after plug in for:

```
namespace Magento\Some_Core\Model\Example;
class Test {
  public function usualMethod(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order) {
    // get order information and attach to $this
    return $this;
  }
}
```

I have my Custom Module's `di.xml` set up and my plug in class as:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Example;
class TestPlugin {
  public function afterUsualMethod(\Magento\Some_Core\Model\Example\Test $subject, $return) {
    $order = $subject->getArguments(0); // ??
    $result->setAdditionalOrderInfo($order->getIAlsoNeedThis());
    return $result;
 }
}
```

Is there any way to access the `$order` object passed in the original method? I can easily extend the original class and call `parent::usualMethod()` but wanted to know if it was possible to use a plugin for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Example;
class TestPlugin {
    public function afterUsualMethod(\Magento\Some_Core\Model\Example\Test $subject, $result, $order) {
        $result->setAdditionalOrderInfo($order->getIAlsoNeedThis());
        return $result;
    }
}
```

[More detail](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: Worked like a charm! thx!